# SwiftUI List issues in offscreen elements

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have put together a quick folder explorer to view a bunch of images in subfolders. Basically, given a path, it looks for folders and gives you a button to expand the folders and show the images inside.

Below is the code I put together. However, if the `List` cell is drawn offscreen, the `Button` never shows up once it is scrolled into view. Can anyone replicate this? How do I fix it? Is it just a bug in SwiftUI?

### EDIT: For clarity, this is macOS Catalyst.

Here's where the list is used:

```
List(folderurls, id: \.self) { url in
    ListImageViewer(url: url)
}
```

And here's the full code for `ListImageViewer`:

```
struct ListImageViewer: View {
    var url: URL
    @State var expanded: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if expanded {
                self.coordinator.refreshListing(for: self.url)
            } else {
                self.coordinator.contents = []
            }
        }
    }
    @ObservedObject var coordinator = FolderListingCoordinator()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.expanded.toggle()
                }) { Text(self.expanded ? "Collapse" : "Expand") }
                Text("\(url.lastPathComponent)")
            }

            HStack {
                ForEach(coordinator.contents, id: \.self) { url in
                    ImageView(url: url)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you try using `ScrollView` instead of `List`?

Comment: Yes, this solves the issue of elements not being drawn, but performance is unusably slow.

Comment: how many elements do you have? Maybe you need to load them in chunks? From experience `List` seems buggy or at least not suitable for everything... maybe its by design

Comment: 300 items. this wouldn't be hard for a NSTableView.

Comment: I never tried loading so many objects into a `ScrollView`...

Comment: Agreed, which is why I chose `List` instead of `ScrollView`. If I were using Cocoa, I'd pick NSTableView. If I were using UIKit, I'd pick `UITableView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welp, I stumbled upon an answer to this question somehow. Once I gave the items in the list the .id modifier, they stopped rendering incorrectly when offscreen.

```
ListImageViewer(url: url)
    .id(url)
```

The performance is poor, but it works as expected finally.

Answer (score 1):

I have submitted a bug for a similar issue. One workaround I discovered was adding a modifier to the VStack that applies to its subviews. For me I had issues drawing TextFields, so I changed the following:

```
var body: some View {
    Section(header: Text("Row \(row)")) {
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
            Text("Name")
            Spacer()
            TextField("Name", text: $name)
                .frame(maxWidth: 120)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
        }
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
            Toggle("Fixed", isOn: $isFixed)
        }
    }
}
```

to

```
var body: some View {
    Section(header: Text("Row \(row)")) {
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
            Text("Name")
            Spacer()
            TextField("Name", text: $name)
                .frame(maxWidth: 120)                    
        }
        HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20) {
            Toggle("Fixed", isOn: $isFixed)
        }
    }.textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
}
```

You may find a similar workaround by adding some style to your containing VStack.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. This didn't really work as well as I expected, so I might just file another bug report.